# Get one Item from array

Tags: php

I have this array `$node->taxonomy` which puts out these data, if I `var_dump()` it:

```
array(1) {
 [4]=>  object(stdClass)#21 (5) {
   ["tid"]=>  string(1) "4"
   ["vid"]=>  string(1) "4"
   ["name"]=>  string(9) "Marketing"
   ["description"]=>  string(0) ""
   ["weight"]=>  string(1) "1"
 }
}
```

how can I extract the element "name" from it?

Answer (score 4):

This way:

```
$node->taxonomy[4]->name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$node->taxonomy[4]->name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo $node->taxonomy[4]->name;
```

or if you don't know the number (or the number changes) but its the first element in the array you could use:

```
<?php
$x = current($node->taxonomy);
echo $x->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
$node->taxonomy[4]->name
```